# Regex format with numbers and one letter

Tags: regex

I would like to know how to create a regex pattern in format:

*111.222-3M*

and

*1112223M*

What are numbers are only numbers allowed, and last one is a letter only.

Thx in advance.

Comment: The question is quite trivial. What specific part did you have trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strict, case-sensitive version:

```
\d{3}\.?\d{3}-?\d[A-Z]
```

Will match *1112223M*, *111.222-3M*, *111.2223M* and *111222-3M*. If the last two are undesirable:

```
(\d{3}\d{3}\d[A-Z])|(\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d[A-Z])
```

Will match only the first two.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your solution too. Its great one. Can I ask you, if its possible to match ONLY to 1st and 2nd type?

Comment: Crazy. How did you learn to make patterns? I would like to learn too. Any suggestions? Please...

Comment: I use RegexBuddy; QuickREx is an open source alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If those really are the only two patterns to match, this will work:

```
^\d+\.?\d+\-?\d+[a-zA-Z]$
```

As @ThomSmith stated, this regex will match numbers with the decimal and hyphen in different locations as well, such as 11.12-2223M. If that is undesirable, let me know.

EDIT:

If those patterns are **exactly** the same as the ones you want to match, this is a better one:

```
^\d{3}\.?\d{3}\-?\d[a-zA-Z]$
```

Comment: Note: this will match strings like 111.2223M or 111222.3M, which may or may not be a problem. Also, I'm not sure if the number of digits may be significant.

Comment: @ThomSmith Good point - I should have specified. I assumed the number of digits before and after the, uh, punctuation? would be fluid. I may or may not have been correct in that assumption

Comment: The only 2 allowed formats are those 2 I showed in my 1st post! So it will work? Else formats must not be passed forward.

Comment: If it's EXACTLY that format (7 numbers and a letter or {3}.{3}-{1}Letter), then a more specific regex should be used. Hang on.

Comment: I did thx. Ok, I will try it out. One more q: will this work for format without any - and . in between?, So in format {7}{1} - 7 numbers and a letter.

Comment: @MitjaBonca Is this part of a larger string? If so, take out the `^` and `$` and try again.